# How to change the default menu icon of component in joomla? currently it's using the box icon

Tags: icons, components, joomla1.5

> hey guys anyone here know how to change the default menu icon of
>   component in joomla? currently it's using the box icon

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the developer, but the 'icons' are decalred in the xml file during installation.  Something like this;

`menu img="../media/foo/foo.png" view="">Control Panel</menu>`

They are typically stored in the media folder, then under the components name.  So if you have already installed the component, just go in an swap the icon. Easy.